# Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack

Tags: c#

```
if (!advertismentsDao.AdvertisementUrlExist(ad.Url))
{
    if (!advertismentsDao.AdvertisementExist(ad.Price, 
                                             ad.HollidayDuration, 
                                             ad.Name, 
                                             ad.Description, 
                                             ad.City, 
                                             ad.Area, 
                                             ad.Country,
                                             ad.Agency))
    {
       advertismentsDao.Save(ad);
       advertismentsDao.CommitChanges(); 
    }
}
```

gives me:

> InnerException = Unable to evaluate
>   expression because the code is
>   optimized or a native frame is on top
>   of the call stack.

error is wheren i got here CommitChanges(). I google but i can not solve my problem

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suspect that's not *actually* the inner exception - I suspect that's just what the debugger's showing you when you try to inspect the exception.

Dump a complete stack trace to a log instead, and that should give the *real* exception, which should then make it clear why the commit failed.

Answer (score 2):

It is caused due to ThreadAbortException .. Just use the below code at the end of your code block . It might solve your problem .

```
/*

 catch (System.Threading.ThreadAbortException)
 { }

*/
```